# Non-Schema Data Migrations (Data Fixes)

Tags: laravel, migration

There are times when we need to change some of the data values in our production environment.

For example, say we have a choice every user must make. The values for each choice are "choice 1" and "choice 2". For some reason, we must change "choice 2" to "choice b" and all users who previously selected "choice 2" must be updated to "choice b".

We currently handle this situation by creating an artisan command and running it in production.

Is this the best way to do this?

I think an ideal solution would be to have something similar to migrations, where the last one added gets run during deployment. Are there any packages that do this?

How do other companies handle this situation?

Any links to helpful articles would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When you migrate your tables, they are empty. There are no values. No "choice 2" or "choice b".

After you migrate your tables, you may choose to seed them. That's when you add some default values or dump a bunch of insert queries from that big `.sql` file.

You could just make a seeder that changes that value.